# How to quickly add namespace declarations in a spring bean config file via STS

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am extending a project that uses spring framework. It is always a painful task to manually add these xsd declarations by copy/paste both the ns and the schemaLocation. I noticed there is a step to visually select all the xsd available within the project when you initially create the xml file. Is there a similar way to do that when modifying the xml?

Also is there any way that can automatically format the namespaces introduced but not used. Something like command(ctrl) + shift + o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In STS, you can easily and quickly configure the namespace declarations using the Spring Config Editor.

You need to right click on the spring context you would like to configure, select Open With -> Spring Config Editor. In the Spring Config Editor, at the bottom, next to the Source tab, you can find the Namaspaces tab. In this tab you can easily add/remove namespaces.

As for your second question, I'm not sure if something similar to (ctrl) + shift + o command exists for spring namespaces.